# Approximate null space of an almost singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

I have a matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix}-0.0550 & -0.0870 & 0.6480 & 0.9830\\ 0.6270 & 0.9730 & 0.9840 & 0.3790\\ 0.6330 & 0.9830 & 0.5530 & -0.2260 \\ -0.1480 & -0.2310 & 0.9270 & 1.5130 \end{bmatrix}$$ and its determinant is $-2.55\cdot10^{-7}$. This matrix is almost singular. I apply SVD to $A$ and find $$\sigma_1=2.3498,\ \sigma_2=1.8096,\ \sigma_3=0.0005,\ \sigma_4=0.0001.$$ I want to know how to find a set $x$ for which $Ax$ is ''small'' can be regarded as an approximate null space. I assume I need to use $\sigma_3$ and $\sigma_4$ because entries of the last two columns of $AV$ are small.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look into the [Eckart-Young theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation).

In a nutshell, write $A = \sum_i \sigma_i u_i v_i^T$ as the SVD where $\sigma_i$ are the singular values in descending order, and $u_i,v_i$ are the left and right respective singular vectors. If you let $A_k = \sum_{i \leq k} \sigma_i u_i v_i^T$, then $A_k$ an the optimal approximation of $A$ with rank $k$ in the Frobenius norm (and in fact, for any unitarily invariant norm).

If you take $x= v_i$, then $\lVert Ax \rVert = \sigma_i$. So, you could consider the span of the small right singular vectors as your approximate null space (which is the null space of the optimal rank $k$ approximation as above).

Comment: I think it is late to ask. Is there a way to find the basis for this null space?

Comment: As I said in the last sentence, the null space of the rank $k$ approximation is given by $span(v_{i+1},v_{i+2},\ldots)$.

Answer (score 3):

@Batman has succinctly answered the question. Numerical details follow.

---

The matrix $\mathbf{A}$ has a singular value decomposition of the form
$$
\begin{align}
%
  \mathbf{A} &=
%
\left[
\begin{array}{llll}
 -0.055 & -0.087 & \phantom{-} 0.648 & \phantom{-} 0.983 \\
 \phantom{-} 0.627 & \phantom{-} 0.973 & \phantom{-} 0.984 & \phantom{-} 0.379 \\
 \phantom{-} 0.633 & \phantom{-} 0.983 & \phantom{-} 0.553 & -0.226 \\
 -0.148 & -0.231 & \phantom{-} 0.927 & \phantom{-} 1.513 \\
\end{array}
\right] \\[3pt]
&=
%
  \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*} =
% 
\mathbf{U} \, 
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 2.34981 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1.80958 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0.000464489 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.000129511 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\, \mathbf{V}^{*}
\end{align}
$$
The matrix $\mathbf{A}$ has rank $\rho=4$ and has a condition number of $$
\kappa_{2} = \frac{\sigma_{1}} {\sigma_{\rho}} \approx 18000
$$

---

You are asking about a *low-rank approximation.* (E.g., [Low-rank Approximation with SVD on a Kernel Matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205651/low-rank-approximation-with-svd-on-a-kernel-matrix/2207592#2207592)) A sequence of approximations follows.

For example, the rank $2$ approximation uses the $2$ largest eigenvalues 
$$
 \mathbf{A}_{2} = \mathbf{U} \, 
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 2.34981 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1.80958 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\, \mathbf{V}^{*}
$$
The total error is
$$
 \epsilon_{2} =
 \lVert \mathbf{A} - \mathbf{A}_{2} \rVert_{2}
$$
The errors are plotted below for expansions using the largest eigenvalue, the two largest singular values, the three largest singular values, and all singular values.

[image: errors]

---

### $k = 4$

The full rank case uses all $4$ singular values to reconstruct the input matrix 
$$\mathbf{A}_{4} =
% 
\mathbf{U} \, 
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 2.34981 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1.80958 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0.000464489 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.000129511 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\, \mathbf{V}^{*}
$$

[image: A4]

The total error is numerical noise
$$
 \epsilon_{4} =
 \lVert \mathbf{A} - \mathbf{A}_{4} \rVert_{2} = 1.17 \times 10^{-15}
$$

---

### $k = 3$

The next case uses the $3$ largest singular values to reconstruct the input matrix 
$$\mathbf{A}_{3} =
% 
\mathbf{U} \, 
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 2.34981 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1.80958 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0.000464489 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\, \mathbf{V}^{*}
$$

[image: A3]

The total error is negligible
$$
 \epsilon_{3} =
 \lVert \mathbf{A} - \mathbf{A}_{3} \rVert_{2} = 0.00013
$$

The row and column space both has a null space of dimension $1$, and these vectors are already computed; they are the final column vectors for the column and row space matrices. 
$$
%
\begin{align}
%
\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A} \right) &= 
\text{span } \left\{ \, \mathbf{V}_{4} \, \right\} \\
%
\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right) &= 
\text{span } \left\{ \, \mathbf{U}_{4} \, \right\}
%
\end{align}
%
$$

---

### $k = 2$

This case uses the $2$ largest singular values to reconstruct the input matrix 
$$\mathbf{A}_{2} =
% 
\mathbf{U} \, 
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 2.34981 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1.80958 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\, \mathbf{V}^{*}
$$

[image: A2]

The total error is comparable to the previous case
$$
 \epsilon_{3} =
 \lVert \mathbf{A} - \mathbf{A}_{3} \rVert_{2} = 0.00046
$$

Now the row and column space both have a null space of dimension $2$; the final $2$ column vectors for the column and row space matrices. 
$$
%
\begin{align}
%
\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A} \right) &= 
\text{span } \left\{ \, \mathbf{V}_{3}, \, \mathbf{V}_{4} \, \right\} \\
%
\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right) &= 
\text{span } \left\{ \, \mathbf{U}_{3}, \, \mathbf{U}_{4} \, \right\}
%
\end{align}
%
$$

---

### $k = 1$

The last case uses only the largest singular value
$$\mathbf{A}_{1} =
% 
\mathbf{U} \, 
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 2.34981 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\, \mathbf{V}^{*}
$$

[image: A1]

The total error
$$
 \epsilon_{4} =
 \lVert \mathbf{A} - \mathbf{A}_{4} \rVert_{2} = 1.80958
$$
is comparable to the size of the input matrix
$$
  \lVert \mathbf{A} \rVert_{2} = 2.34981
$$

The null spaces follow. 
$$
%
\begin{align}
%
\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A} \right) &= 
\text{span } \left\{ \, \mathbf{V}_{2}, \, \mathbf{V}_{3}, \, \mathbf{V}_{4} \, \right\} \\
%
\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right) &= 
\text{span } \left\{ \, \mathbf{U}_{2}, \, \mathbf{U}_{3}, \, \mathbf{U}_{4} \, \right\}
%
\end{align}
%
$$

---

The panels below compare the low rank approximations more directly.

[image: grid]